# In EF of oracle, data type conversion occurs when SQL is generated by linq, which makes SQL more complex and less efficient

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I hope that when querying, the data type will not be converted,and need not to change database and model

I tried to use short,int,byte as a parameter type, but it didn't work.

```
short type=1;
var list=dbcontext.table.where(d=>d.type == type);
```

ef sql
    select * from table where (cast(type as number(10,0))) = 1

But the SQL I want to get is
    select * from table where type  = 1

Comment: what is the dataType of type in table?

Comment: @Tanveer Hasan number(1,0)

Comment: Dont use number, use integer instead. if you use number linq convert it as decimal

Comment: I know integer can do it ,but my leader want to try something else.Don't change the database

Comment: What happens if you declare `type` as `float` (or `double`) and assign `1.0` to it? In SQL (at least the Oracle implementation) you get no benefit from comparing integers, or doing arithmetic with integers.

Comment: No matter which ORM you use you'll encounter issues similar to this. The only way to get the SQL you want, every time, is to write the SQL you want, every time.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use number, use integer instead. if you use number linq convert it as decimal

```
decimal type=1;
var list=dbcontext.table.where(d=>d.type == type);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , but if use decimal ,the sql will be select * from table where (cast(type as  number(19,0)))=1

Answer (score 0):

I would use an Enum instead. All Enum properties have an Integer value. So they get cast to Integers automatically. Also when using Enum you can use Enum.IsDefined as stated by the OWASP Cheat Sheet if you're working with Integers somewhere else.

**See:** https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/DotNet_Security_Cheat_Sheet.md#data-access